# Habilitar un input, cuando se completa el formulario

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

mi boton "enviar" le puse un modal de BS, pero quiero que el boton este desactivado, hasta que se completen los datos, hice las funciones pero no me funciona...
Muestro el codigo por si alguien me puede ayudar.

```
 html
       boton <input type="submit" value="enviar" class="btn btn-dark buttom-tienda" id="open-modal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal">
                        <!-- modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                              <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Gracias!</h5>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                  <p id="">Gracias, te contactaremos via E-mail.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
```

Este es el codigo que tengo de JS y no me lo esta tomando, osea no me lo activa cuando completo los datos.

```
function habilitar(){
    let nombreApellido = document.getElementById("nombreApellido");
    let email = document.getElementById("email");
    let selector = document.getElementById("provincias");
    let enviarBoton = document.getElementById("open-modal");

    val = 0;
    console.log("HOLA");
    if (nombreApellido.value === ''){
        val++;
    }
    if (email.value === ''){
        val++;
    }
    if (val === 0) {
        enviarBoton.disabled = false;
    } else {
        enviarBoton.disabled = true;
    }
    console.log(nombreApellido.value);
}

nombreApellido.addEventListener("onblur", habilitar());
email.addEventListener("onblur", habilitar());
selector.addEventListener("change", habilitar());
document.getElementById("open-modal").addEventListener("click", () => {
    alert("haz completador todo")
});
```

Comment: El boton responde al click, para determinar si responde al submit falta el formulario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los eventos `onblur`, `onchange`, etc, se pueden declarar en línea para ejecutar la función `habilitar()`. El botón, por su parte, lo puedes dejar inactivo por defecto con la propiedad `disabled`.

Luego, desde `JavaScript`, puedes declarar la función, capturar los `value` de cada objeto y comparar si están vacíos o no para habilitar el botón.

Ejecuta el snippet para que compruebas que funciona.

```js
function habilitar() {
  let nombreApellido = document.getElementById("nombreApellido");
  let email = document.getElementById("email");
  let selector = document.getElementById("provincias");
  let enviarBoton = document.getElementById("open-modal");

  if (nombreApellido.value === '' || email.value === '' || selector.value === '') {
    enviarBoton.disabled = true;
  } else {
    enviarBoton.disabled = false;
  }
}

document.getElementById("open-modal").addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert("Haz completado todo!")
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nombreApellido" onblur="habilitar()"><br>
<input type="text" id="email" onblur="habilitar()"><br>
<select id="provincias" onchange="habilitar()">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">Cataluña</option>
</select><br><br>
<button id="open-modal" disabled>Enviar</button>
```